# How to search in `std::list` of struct?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, stdlist

The problem is that I can not search in a `std::list`, according to the user-input `vID`.

I have tried many different approaches but it did not work.

```
struct VideoDetails
{
  int VidID, Copies;
  string MovieTitle, Genre, Production, FileName;

};
list <VideoDetails> MyList;
int vID;
cin >> vID;
```

**First attempt**:

```
find_if(MyList.begin(), MyList.end(), [](VideoDetails & VD) {return VD.VidID == vID; });
```

**Second attempt**:

```
auto pred = [](const VideoDetails & ID) { return ID.VidID == vID;  };
find_if(Mylist.begin(), MyList.end(), vID) != MyList.end();
```

**Third attempt**:

```
list <VideoDetails>::iterator iter;
for(iter = MyList.begin(); iter != MyList.end(); ++iter)
{
  if ((*iter).VidID == vID) {
    //  
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

---

**First attempt error**:

```
Error (active) E1738 the enclosing-function 'this' cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list mp 3
```

**Third attempt error**:

```
Error C2678 binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) mp 3
```

Answer (score 4):

**First method**: You did not capture the `vID` inside the lambda, that's what the error message complaining about.

```
const auto iter = std::find_if(MyList.begin(), MyList.end(), 
                  [vID](const VideoDetails& VD) {return VD.VidID == vID; });
         //        ^^^^
```

And do not forget to get the iterator returning from `std::find_if`, in case of further use. If you correct the above, your first method will work.

**Second method**: Has no big difference than the one. The lambda has the same problem as the above. In addition to that *[`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)* required an unary predicate, not a value to be found in the container. Change to

```
auto pred = [vID](const VideoDetails & ID) {   return ID.VidID == vID; }
//           ^^^^
if(std::find_if(Mylist.begin(), MyList.end(), pred ) != MyList.end())
//                                            ^^^^
{
   // do something
}
```

If you have made work with the `std::find_if` and lambda, you do not need to go for the third attempt.

Comment: E1738 the enclosing-function 'this' cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list

Comment: E1730 member "MyClass::vID" is not a variable

Comment: the second error exist when i put "vID" in the lambda

Comment: @lRinzu I assume there is a class where you have the above codes. Those are the error messages from the code you have not shown above. Please update or create a new question with a [minimal complete example which produces the above-mentioned errors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then can only someone help you better.